# Unable to copy file from docker-compose mount to host

Tags: selenium, docker, protractor, docker-compose

I am unable to copy a file generated by my Selenium tests in a folder inside docker container mounted to host machine.

Here is how my compose file look like

```
  selenium:
    image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
    expose:
      - "4444"
  tests:
    build:
      context: ./tests
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - selenium
      - web
    volumes:
      - /testResultsReport:/testResultsReport
```

This is how my directory structure looks like.

```
\
 - docker-compose.yml
 - build scripts
 - tests
   - testResultsReport
   - Test scripts
```

Name of the file generated inside testResultsReport folder when running docker-compose is `TestResultsReport.HTML`

As my tests are running inside selenium server on port `4444`, should I mount my volume there? I tried doing that to but still not getting my html file copied to host machine?
I confirmed that my html file is generated when i run my tests outside compose.

I also tried ./testResultsReport however it added a folder in root with name of testResultsReport and did nothing. So I used ./tests/testResultsReport but still not getting file.

Comment: Try `./testResultsReport`, that is a relative file path, while `/` would be absolute. So: `- ./testResultsReport:/testResultsReport`

Comment: I tried `./testResultsReport` however it added a folder in root with name of testResultsReport and did nothing. So I used `./tests/testResultsReport` but still not getting file.

Comment: Thanks. Worked by using `./tests/testResultsReport:/tests/testResultsReport`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked by using right folder and absolute path. Thanks @chrisz

```
selenium:
    image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
    expose:
      - "4444"
  tests:
    build:
      context: ./tests
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - selenium
      - web
    volumes:
      - ./tests/testResultsReport:/tests/testResultsReport
```